# How to change Background and Foreground Color for Navigation Item title in iOS Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift

**Hi all....** I'm Confused with *forground* color attributes in **navigationitem.title** in swift 2.0 .. i already try these codes below

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor =  UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
      navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

It change **BarColor and BackButton color** for all viewcontroller(connect as push segue)
But i cannot access ***navigationItem.title  color*** methods. s**o how to change this title color?**.. thanks in advance :) ;)

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcC7W.png)

Comment: You mean you want to change the title text color?

Comment: mmm Yess... I want to change title text color of navigation item... Mr. John Farkerson answers works very well... thankz man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you are trying to change the text color of your title, you need to put the following in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in **`AppDelegate.swift`**:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Happy to help! @MohanSingh